# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found when I try to import matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, sublimetext3, libraries

Hello I just started Python with sublime 3 text. Whenever I try to import some libraries such as matplot lib this error message pop :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\delac\KaggleProject\HousePrice.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\delac\.venvs\lewagon\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\delac\.venvs\lewagon\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

If anyone know how to help me I thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you install `pip install matplotlib`?

Answer (score 0):

alan delachair,

try to install mini conda ,then go in command window ,

```
type "conda activate pandas,python,matplotlib,numpy
```

it will download everything in one go.